# Is there a method string.TryFormat that works similar to string.Format?

Tags: .net, string, exception

Is there anyway to check if a string.format argument is valid argument something like string.TryFormat .

```
try
{
    string.Format(Format, new string[Selectors.Count]); //
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return false; 
}
```

I am using this method in my UI and its slow and noticable when an Exception is catched, so i was wondering if there is a better method to use.

I could always write my own method but i wanted to know if there is a pre defined one.

An invalid string Format would be something like this string.Format("Format{0}{1}{2}",new string[]{"a","b" })

Comment: And what did you find in [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods.aspx)? (I'm assuming you're talking about the .Net runtime here, although you haven't actually said...)

Comment: yeah i should have mentioned that ia m talking about the .Net runtime . But i did not find what i need in the MSDN docs

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? It sounds like you're using a heavy-handed solution when there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: In my UI the user can change the format string and can add/remove the corresponding strings to a List of strings. I need to be able to tell him that his format is invalid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way a `System.String.TryFormat` method could work would be to catch any exceptions that might be thrown from various implementations of `IFormattable.ToString` (although a `String.TryFormat` could replace some of its own exceptions with an error-flag return, doing that while letting exceptions from `TryFormat` escape wouldn't be very helpful).

Worse, a `TryFormat` method wouldn't have any way of knowing whether any of the exceptions thrown by `IFormattable.ToString` might be things which shouldn't be caught.  Even if the `IFormattable.ToString` contract required that implementations should not leak anything other than `FormatException` if a format specifier was invalid, one would probably want a `String.TryFormat` method to return false (rather than throwing) if some of the input objects were invalid but attempting to format them hadn't made anything any worse, while leaking an exception if the act of trying to format items had itself caused corruption.  Unfortunately, the way the exception hierarchy is set up, there's no way a `String.TryFormat` could even begin to approach such semantics.

Simply put, there's not much that a `String.TryFormat` method could do other than use a `try`/`catch` block to stifle exceptions thrown by interior methods.  There's a normal implication that `TryXX` methods are supposed to work better in the failure case than would be a consumer routine which just did `XX` in a try-catch block.  If the `TryFormat` method is simply going to work by stifling exceptions anyway, it may as well let the consumer handle that.

Comment: Thank you for the intensive Explanation

Comment: Why don’t they do it like `System.Text.Decoder` with a pair of `Convert`/ `GetCharCount`.
`Convert` just decode as long as there is space in the buffer. The next call continues to decode the new buffer from the breakpoint. And if you want to decode at a time, you can pre-calculate the buffer size by `GetCharCount`.
`TryFormat` does not seem to be the most optimal in terms of performance - it first calculates the required buffer size, and in case of insufficient size it forces you to make a repeated call, which re-performs all these validations and calculations.